# My script can read a text file when run manually through ISE, but it looks in a different directory when run through Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell

Powershell noob here.

I have a script for copying PDF documents and CSV files. The script gets the CSV data from a URL defined in a .txt file in the same directory as the script. In the script, the file is determined like this:

`$publishedCSV = Get-Content .\DriveURL.txt -Raw`

When I run this script in ISE, it works fine and retrieves all the CSV data. However, when I run it in Scheduler, it tries to find the DriveURL file in System32, rather than in the path that is specified (I used transcript to find out what was happening)

I figured that out, and defined the FULL path of DriveURL, rather than just using the .\ notation. It works, but I don't know why it works

What I did:
Specified proper path of DriveURL and now my script works. I don't understand why it worked previously with using ./DriveURL.txt rather than the full path when I'd run it in ISE, but it didn't when run in Scheduler. It's the same script

Answer (score 0):

If you use relative paths then you must also either set your working directory, or in the script change to the appropriate directory before referencing said relative paths. Alternatively you can use full paths, as you have already discovered.

A simple use of `cd` or `pushd` and the automatic `$PSScriptRoot` variable will change your working directory to wherever the script is saved to:

```
pushd $PSScriptRoot
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I actually had $PSScriptRoot but it was below the line that grabbed the file. Just stuck it up a few lines and presto